# Are there any ways to prevent the IE8 'pause' as an ajax response is dealt with by jquery/javascript, if not, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

Viewing http://twitter.com/BBCNews as an example in IE8, as you scroll down the page, triggering the infinite scroll, there's a perceptible 'pause' as IE8 mulls over the ajax response, and during this pause, a user cannot scroll.

The time the javascript engine actually takes to deal with the response is not a huge issue, I get that that's just that IE8 being a bit slow, but the inability to scroll during this time leads to a pretty miserable user experience because the ajax responses are so regular. I often tend to find that 50% of time on the page with IE8 is waiting to be able to scroll again.

As far as being a user is concerned, I can't detect any such pause with more modern browsers, I can still seem to scroll up despite an ajax response still being processed and not yet appended (though perhaps it's just running too fast to tell).

I'm guessing if twitter don't have a solution to this then there's a good chance the answer will be No, but as I couldn't find a definitive answer I thought I'd ask. I'm not asking for pointers on improving javascript performance *speed* on IE8, but that if while javascript is processing an ajax response, is it possible to still enable a user to still scroll up, for example, before the response data has been processed and appended.

Comment: What pause are you referring to? The ajax loader seems to behave in chrome and IE (detect scroll bottom -> load content using ajax -> append).

Comment: Do you mean that the user cannot scroll _at all_ during this 'pause'?

Comment: The answer is "upgrade your browser". Duh.

Comment: Yes that a user cannot scroll at all during the pause. If you scroll to the bottom of the twitter feed in the question, the ajax load triggers (at this point you can still scroll), but when the ajax response is received (just go frantic with the mouse wheel to test) scroll stops until the response is processed and appended.

Comment: I'm not asking as a user, as a developer. But I'm interested in whether its possible to have the browser not stall while it processes a response, rather than speeding up how long it takes to process it. I don't use IE8 personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is probably in how much work you need to do when a response is received.

Minimise the amount of work done when the response is received. If you have lots of work to do, you could consider splitting it up into smaller chunks and doing it bit-by-bit on a timer.

Comment: Ditto I'm not asking as a user, as a developer. But I'm interested in whether its possible to have the browser not stall while it processes a response, I'm no interested in this question about speeding up how long it takes to process it. I don't use IE8 personally. It's probably not possible. Edit: but no I don't work for Twitter

Comment: As I said, break the work up into smaller chunks and do them one at a time in timer. This gives the browser a chance to respond to other events.

Comment: I see what you mean after looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357361/how-to-freeze-web-browsers-repaints-while-changing-visibility-of-elements with this example http://jsbin.com/ecuku/edit So javascript execution locks the browser, and the only way to make the pause shorter is to split processing into chunks. Thank you