# .hide().show() in single event causes rerendering?

Tags: jquery

Blitz question. Will it do anything if I call `element.hide(); ....something...... element.show();` in a single `click` event? I mean, unwanted flickering, heavy calculations etc.? Why I need this? Because it is quite elegant in my code to hide everything and decide what to show then.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, guys, yesterday I looked into jQuery sources myself and found that (as @Msencenb said) hide/show is just a wrapper for `display:none`.

So I update my question: will browser do some immediate rerendering and recalculations on `display:none` and then immediate rerendering and recalculations on `display:block` in a single `.click(function() { ... })`? Or it detects that nothing has changed after `click` function and do nothing?

Comment: The best way to figure out something like this is to try it: http://jsfiddle.net/rud9j0h7/

Answer (score 1):

the .hide() event is just a wrapper around adding a 'display' : 'none' css property. From a performance perspective this means that the browser is simply going to need to repaint that content when it becomes visible again which is going to be highly dependent on what you are actually rendering. [Chrome dev tools has some really cool stuff for profiling.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline)

As far as unwanted flickering, you should look into callbacks. Most jquery functions take an optional callback that will run after the function completes.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( ".hideme" ).hide(function() {
        $(".hideme").show();
      });
    });
});
```

[Here's a simple example using hide/show](http://jsfiddle.net/thxu1p28/1/)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the browser doesn't repaint until it finishes execution of the current code. This would seem quite logical, as you might be setting various style properties separately and wouldn't want the browser to re-paint in the middle of all that. However, I can't find any documentation to support this claim at short notice.

Edit: You might want to peruse [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357361/how-to-freeze-web-browsers-repaints-while-changing-visibility-of-elements).