# Coalescing or Batching HTML Parsing

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, updates

I am working on a project that requires updates to many html elements. The issue is I find that I am getting slower than desired performance, even on high end machines. Now when I do each update, my browser (both chrome and firefox) attempts to reparse the page.

[image: Many small html updates turn into a lot of browser work]

Is there a way I can tell the browser "Hey I am going to be doing a bunch of html updates, don't bother reparsing until I say so"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript execution blocks the browser from performing repaints, but not reflows, which occurs when the browser has to recalculate positions of elements. I would suggest cloning the nodes which you need to change using [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) then alter the new nodes and insert them into the DOM all at once.

Here is a very similar question [How to freeze web browser's repaints while changing visibility of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357361/how-to-freeze-web-browsers-repaints-while-changing-visibility-of-elements)